# Relationship is between Apache2 and xsp2 (or mono-xsp2) for an Ubuntu Linux 16.04 system which serves mono ASP-NET content to an web browser user

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, asp.net

I am interested in knowing what is the relationship is between Apache2 and xsp2 (or mono-xsp2) for an Ubuntu Linux 16.04 system which serves mono ASP-NET content to an web browser user requesting an WebForm, hello.aspx.

What does it mean to serve mono ASP-NET content versus serving ASP-NET content?

Is it possible to do this with only Apache2 and dependent configuration files?

[EDIT June 12 2016 10:42 PM]
Quoting from ,mod_mono,which is the title of this article,  http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/mod_mono/
"mod_mono.conf loads the mod_mono module, associates ASP.NET file extensions with the ASP.NET MIME type and adds index.aspx, Default.aspx, and default.aspx as automatic directory index pages (with the DirectoryIndex directive). If you don’t include mod_mono.conf in your main Apache configuration, you will at least need to have the mod_mono.so module loaded with:

LoadModule mono_module /usr/lib/httpd/modules/mod_mono.so
For more detailed configuration and manual tuning keep reading.

mod_mono will automatically launch mod-mono-server and start the web application on the first request for a page handled by mod_mono. In the early days of mod_mono, you had to start mod-mono-server by yourself, ensuring that it had all the parameters needed to understand the requests forwarded by the module. This is still an option for those who want mod-mono-server to have a separate life cycle from apache, but you will probably prefer to use mod_mono built-in ability to start and stop mod-mono-server for you"

Comment: `xsp` run on `mono`, `mono` is the C# runtime for *nix.  Therefore your question is whether `mono asp-net` needs the C# runtime, right?  I never wrote any `asp-net` but i believe that the `_mod` for `apache` for **any** `asp-net` needs a C# runtime.

Comment: @grochmal, Thank you for your nice comment. I just pasted an excerpt from Mono foundation's document on mod_mono at the end of my original question . My written English is not as good as yours. Please restate the relationship between xsp2 and Apache.

Comment: I did a quick research and i can say that: `mod_mono` depends on `xsp` which depends on `mono` itself.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34337160/6327365) by one of mono developers which confirms part of that dependency chain. Therefore (on linux) you need `mono` to run any `asp.net`, in turn that means that there is no difference between running `mono asp.net` or `asp.net` (whatever the difference might be).